# Can I transfer a mysql database by moving a file?

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

I have installed xampp on my Ubuntu machine, and would like to be able to move the database to another computer. I was wondering if the database is stored as a file, similar to an Access database (mdb), such that I could just copy the database file, and if so, where it would likely be installed to. At this point, I know very little about how mysql works, so for all I know, this question doesn't even make sense. If someone could explain this, I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right from the source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html